# C++ DirectShow Video and Audio capture - beginning 

Tags: c++, directx, directshow, webcam

I have finally managed to drop working with VFW after several problems I have encountered during the application development.

Thanks to StackOverflow, I am now aware that VFW is obsolete and wish to switch to DShow, to let my application work with Vista/W7.

Unfortunately, the work has been made and application has been shipped to the client, but as soon as we realized we have troubles with frame rates on Vista / W7 - we decided to rewrite the video class and use DirectShow to establish a good audio/video capture engine for webcameras.

This will be tricky, as we never coded with DShow, and right now we are looking for few specific examples of how to:

- Connect to a selected webcamera

  **similar to: capDriverConnect**
- Set camera resolution to 640x480 and RGB24 format ( we need to do RGB24 to YUV420 for each frame )

  **similar to: capSetVideoFormat / capCaptureSetSetup**
- Set audio capturing for this webcamera

  **similar to: capSetAudioFormat**
- Register two callbacks:

  - One for video frame ( we will pass frames to video encoder )

  **similar to: capSetCallbackOnVideoStream**

  - One for wave buffer ( we will pass wave buffer to audio encoder )

  **similar to: capSetCallbackOnWaveStream**
- Be able to show a preview window somewhere on parent window

  **similar to: capPreview**
- Perform Start/Stop operation when needed

  - Start - would mean, connect and start capturing audio/video frames
  - Disconnect - would mean, stop capturing audio video frames
- Perform drawing to the actual frame

  similar to:

  SetBitmapBits(CameraInput.GetFrameBitmap(),w*h*3,vdhdr->lpData);
  // draw something with gdi+
  GetBitmapBits(CameraInput.GetFrameBitmap(),w*h*3,vdhdr->lpData);//set back the frame with data

All of the above was already made with VFW, but as I wrote before we unfortunately need to switch do Direct Show.

Is there anyone who could help us out achieving a class that could rescue us from months of studying Direct Show ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet for examples will be [the ones from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Your questions are still phrased in terms of VFW so it's hard to answer them as written. For example, in DirectShow you wouldn't register a callback for to encode a video frame. Instead, you'd develop an encoder filter that would receive data from the capture source.

As an alternative, if you're only targeting Vista and later, there is [the Microsoft Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have no experience with it so I don't know how the learning curve compares to DirectShow.

Comment: Thank you, i'll have a look - but now i am totally lost what to use DShow or Microsoft Media Framework. What's the difference..?

Comment: Media Foundation (got the name wrong, edited my answer to reflect this) looks like a replacement for DirectShow on Vista and later. I think the feature sets overlap. You'll probably find more DirectShow expertise out on the web. I've never used MF so I can't really comment on the advantages/disadvantages.

Comment: Does that mean - that when we will code an application utilizing DShow to work with web camera - it will stop working in 2 years when new Windows will be released ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any plans to drop DirectShow support. Given that VFW is still around I'd wager that DirectShow will be with us for awhile. Microsoft has historically been good about backwards compatibility, but that's no guarantee of anything.

Comment: I would also mess around with GraphEdit as you read up on Dshow. GraphEdit will let you visually build a system to do something video/audio related and DShow will let you build the system programmatically. if you have the windows sdk GraphEdit comes with them or you can try GraphStudio  http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to build a graph on [GraphEdit using FFDshow filters](http://www.digital-digest.com/dvd/downloads/showsoftware_graphedit_141.html).

EditGraph is making a demonstration of building a graph on DirectShow

I don't think  you need you build the filter class by your own. After you'll build the graph and you'd be able to watch the video using GraphEdit. Implementing the graph is [a very simple task](http://www.vwlowen.co.uk/directshow/page01.htm).